# how to configure move_base to run with less memory

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i am simulating serveral robots simultaneously,  i want to do that with around 5-10 robots. But every instance of move_base need at least 1Gb of RAM ,some times they need up to 1.8GB (per instance of move_base).

Why does move_base need so much memory ? Can i reduce the amount of memory if i use a smaller map, or are there any other ways to work with move_base more memory efficently.

regards peter

edit:
answer: if you reduce the map size, the memory size is reduced nerly by the smae percentage, map size reduzed by 75% reduces memory by 80% for me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/116326/how-to-configure-move_base-to-run-with-less-memory/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2014-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2014-01-09**:
is it enough if i configure the slam to build a smaller map or do i need to search/build a smaller map for stage?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-10**:
SLAM is enough. move_base won't know about anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How large are your maps? It's probably the internal costmaps being built. So a smaller map will use less memory.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2014-01-11**:
map was -100 to 100 (standard slam_gmapping values) changed it to -35 to 35 and now it works with less memory , changig the map size solved the problem